# After what size does HashMap become faster than List?

Tags: java, algorithm, search, data-structures

The question is quite simple, what is roughly the number of elements for which the hashing algorithm would be slower than just going through every element of the list to search for it even though HashMap is asymptotically faster? (Using Java's HashMap and ArrayList for example)

Comment: Benchmark it. It really depends on many, many factors. For example a primitive array is orders of magnitude faster than a reference array due to caching behaviour in the CPU. So for a primitive array the answer surprisingly huge if compared to a boxed map. In my experience, for reference types it’s between 10 and 20 elements. But as mentioned - benchmark it on your hardware; this is trivial with JMH.

Comment: I believe it's difficult to give even a rough estimate. First off, what exactly are we comparing here? `ArrayList.contains()` vs. `HashMap.get()`? If so, `ArrayList` specifically iterates the list until first match on `equals()` whereas `HashMap` first calculates the `hashCode()` then traverses the tree. As is evident the relative complexity of `hashCode()` and `equals()` on the stored type may have a big impact on the relative efficiency.

Comment: right, didn't consider the complexity of .equals(), so I guess it's a bit more complicated than I expected, guess I will have to benchmark it. It was more a matter of curiosity, in the end in my application the performance difference is completely negligible.

@jensgram yes that was what I meant, .contains() or something like cycling with for loop until you find what you need.

Thanks a lot for the detailed answers.

Comment: If you look at the source for HashMap, there are a few null/range checks and binary operations happening. But, as long as your objects' hash codes are well-spaced, it's highly likely that they will be the first element in the buckets, meaning no bucket traversal. But it may also be likely that an object is the 0th element in the ArrayList, so it really depends. From my benchmarking, about 6 element is about where the HashMap outperforms an ArrayList (This is at the microsecond scale, remember)